# C# MVC with External Class Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Hello everyone and thanks for your help in advance.  I am learning MVC 5 with C#.  Most of the examples I see are based on a model included in the MVC project.  However, I would think most "real world" applications would utilize some type of external data access library that could be consumed by applications outside of the web app.  With that in mind, I set up a class library with a method to make the database call, populate the model, and return a list.  I called the class library CustomerDB with a class called CustomerDetails.  The data access method, GetCustomerDetails(int custID) returns:

```
List<CustomerDB.CustomerDetails> CustomerDetails
```

specific to the custID.  Then, within the controller of the MVC project, I want to call the external class and retrieve the list, but don't know how incorporate this list into the model of the MVC project.  Any help would be appreciated.

My initial post was generic in details, so let me be more specific.  Here is the code for my external class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace PatientManagerDB
{
public class tblPtmstr1
{
    public int PatientID { get; set; }

    public string PatientLastName { get; set; }

    public string PatientFirstName_Old { get; set; }

    public string PatientFirstName { get; set; }

    public string PatientMiddleName { get; set; }

    public List<tblPtmstr1> PatientDetails = new List<tblPtmstr1>();

    public List<tblPtmstr1> GetPatientDetails(string MRNumber)
    {
        //Code to retrieve data and populate PatientDetails List

    }


}
}
```

My thinking is that, since this class will be used by both the MVC web application as well as other applications, it makes sense to store this in a separate, exterior class, then reference it from whatever application needs it.  Where I am running into problems is how to get the List into some type of usable model in the MVC application.  Within the MVC project, I have tried creating a model:

```
namespace myProject.Models
{

public class Patient
{
    public List<PatientManagerDB.tblPtmstr1> PatientDetails { get; set; }
}
```

Within the controller, I have tried numerous methods to call the GetPatientDetails function and set the Patient property equal to the list returned by the method.  It would seem that most real world applications would function in this manner, not requiring the actual model to be in the MVC application, but I can't seem to figure out how to do this ( or even if it can be done).

Comment: What exactly appears to be a problem ?

Comment: It's the same as if the models were in the same project. Only now the model's namespace has changed -- include the appropriate `using` directive or write out the full namespace.

Comment: try to add reference of the class library which you created into mvc project and call the method and put the result in "var result = CustomerDetails();"

Comment: Typically this is done through nuget packages.  You create the models inside of a project and then create the nuget package from that solution.  Then you import the nuget into the project which will use the models.  This is very common with apis.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/

Comment: I really don't have a problem referencing the models from the external project.  The issue is that the external class also functions as the data access layer, populating the model and returning a List<of.  So the issue is using this list as a model.  I have tried creating a class within the MVC project that is a List<of but can't seem to get the values set.